# Timing issue with jQuery.load and $().ready in the child page

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery Load on a parent page to dynamically insert some child pages from a URL. In the parent page i do something like this:

```
var html = gridDiv.load(self.options.url, function(html, status, xhr)
{
gridDiv.find("myObject:first").data("objectInstance");
    //do something....
});
```

the data object is actually added in the child page during a function that runs on document ready...

```
$().ready(function()
```

What i noticed at first was when running locally everything works as expected. But when deployed on an actual url the load complete event fires before the $().ready completes on the child page.  The first question would be is this correct and is there any way around that so that i can run my code only after $().ready is called on the child page?

I tried a workaround to use a timer in the parent page to check for the element. After a short interval the element will appear in the dom but the data is empty on it. However, if i run the debugger in a button click i can see it all there..

Another workaround attempt was to place the script at the bottom of the child page and then remove the document ready. This too did not work.

Any suggestions? (I cant modify the code logic on the child page too much it needs to be self contained)

Comment: You shouldn't include scripts on child pages loaded in with .load or ajax, they will be executed before the content has been appended resulting in all element selections failing. You can get around it by loading the content as plain text and then parsing out the script tags yourself, then appending the html, and executing the scripts.

Comment: Also, if you want a shorter `$(document).ready(function(){})`, use `$(function(){})`. `$().ready(function(){})` isn't the way that method was intended to be used.

Comment: What seemed to fix everything was removing the jQuery import from the client page. I assume because if is there then that's why my data() on the element in the parent page wasnt found (since it is loading in another memory space?). So what i would suggest to anyone having this problem is try to only load a fragment child page containing the needed script and html.

Answer (score 2):

When you run the code locally you don't really see the loading time delay. Problem with your code is that

```
    $().ready(function(){})
    //executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
```

so I'd suggest you to use

```
    $(window).load(function(){});
    // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects, scripts and images
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. The $(window).load code is never executed when loading the page via the jquery load function.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting the code you want executed into a function, and then on the child page, have it call that function?

For example:

```
//main page
$.ajax({
    url: "child.html",
}).done(function(data, xhr, status){
    $('body').append(data);
});

function child_finished_loading(){
    alert('child is done!');
}
```

and

```
//returned through ajax (child)
<span>This is being appended to main page!</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        child_finished_loading();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Could be a nice comment but it is surely a bad answer

Comment: That's definitely one way of doing it, though the $(function(){}) is useless because by the time the code is executed, the document has probably been parsed for several seconds already. Though it doesn't hurt.

Comment: I agree with you on it's probable uselessness, I just figured better safe than sorry

Comment: That would have been my last attempt. I found that removing the jQuery script imports from the child page worked.